# How to quit a crashed file

Tags: flash-builder

I usually use a two monitor setup that allows me to navigate easily between a window running Flash Builder and one running a browser. This allows me to navigate quickly between FB and the browser and to close the browser window from FB when the browser crashes.

I am away from my office and programming on a laptop. When the browser crashes I have to crash out of FB or else to wait until the Flash plugin fails, both of which are time consuming.
Does anyone know of a fast way to kill an application running in the browser when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Firefox on Windows 7, you can use Windows Task Manager.  Just open Task Manager and end the `plugin-container.exe` process.  Then both the browser and FB should be responsive again.